# Apk Signing Scheme v3: Is it possible to rotate signing certificate, before original certificate expires?

Tags: android, apk

Apk Signature Scheme v3: [follow me](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3)

---

Let's assume you have an app in Google Play Store, whose developer signing certificate will expire shortly.

Can you prevent that from happening, by simply rotating the app signing certificate?
Or is this still not possible, because the original certificate is used to authenticate the new one?

Answer (score 0):

The expiration date of the certificate is currently ignored by the Android platform and Google Play, so nothing bad will happen when it expires.

Google Play does not support certificate rotation today.